# How do I obtain decorative gems?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I have finished all but some very minor quests (e.g. collect all shards) in the Hinterlands, which means I purged area from templars, mages, bandits and so on.

At the very same time, I'm upgrading my fortress. For a tapestry upgrade, I need 4 decorative gems. According to our almighty Google, it seems those are drops from all sort of scapegraces which I banished from the area.

In short, consider the situation - is there a way to farm or buy or in any other way get these 4 decorative gems?

Answer (score 2):

There's a guaranteed spawn of 3 templars 10 o'clock from the Dwarfson's Pass camp. Go up the stony little path and they will be near the hut. The hut is just south of the cliffs/treeline on your map.

This is after I killed all the mage and templar quests.

I needed two extra gems and I got 1 drop each time I killed the group. So it's rinse and repeat depending how many you need. I visited Haven and went back for the re-spawn.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you complete the quests, there will still be random spawns of bandits, mages, and templars. It might take some time before you can gather your quest materials though. Make sure you don't sell them to a vendor.

Answer (score 0):

When your at the hut that is north west of the camp make a save, then reload the save. This will make the mages and Templars spawn. This may take several reloads. You can get the gems, fereldan locks and the skulls.  Be patient

Answer (score 0):

Almost directly north of house is a single stone with a braiser and dirt rings around it. They spawn there.